# How do I show the MM/DD that were Saturdays for the last 30 days

Tags: sql-server

I was handed a query that has 4 versions of this query up in the select clause

```
SELECT 
    STUFF( (SELECT DISTINCT '; ' + 
       LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST( ADT2.EffectiveDTS AS DATE),101), 5) 
FROM ADT AS ADT2 
WHERE 
    DATENAME(dw, ADT2.EffectiveDTS) = 'Saturday' AND 
    CAST(ADT2.EffectiveDTS AS DATE) BETWEEN DATEADD(D, -30, CAST(ADT.EffectiveDTS AS DATE)) AND 
    CAST(ADT.EffectiveDTS AS DATE) FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1,'')) AS Saturdays,
```

This particular query spits out this   `10/08` ; `10/29`; `10/15`; `10/22` to the SATURDAYs column.

My first step was to bring in a calendar table to use in the JOIN connection.

```
INNER JOIN Reference.Calendar CAL
ON CAL.CalendarDTS     = CAST(ADT.EffectiveDTS AS DATE)
```

I wasn't sure if casting the DateTime field would be efficient but with an index on the date the query dropped from 35 seconds to 1 for 18K rows which is six days of data.

I was surprised at that improvement, but then I ran it back to Jan 2015. That caused me to have to kill the query after about 10 minutes. I know those upper select statements are causing issues, my execution plan is hideous.

So now I am trying to think of the best way to replace those queries. FYI, I am limited to using a view because of the tool my company uses. Otherwise I am sure I could do a lot better with a Proc.

Comment: what is the data type for EffectiveDTS?  casting it as a date is probably part of what's killing your query

Comment: It is a DateTime2 field. I casted it as a DATE in order to join to my calendar table. That took the query from 37 seconds down to 2. I have yet to put the calendar date in the Selects running in the main Select. I was just assuming there was a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need Saturdays from last 30 days then you can use a query something like....

```
Declare @Date DATE = GETDATE();


-- Get Saturdays in last 30 days 
Select CONVERT(VARCHAR(5) , DATEADD(DAY, Nums , @Date ), 1) [Date]
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 30  -1 * ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) Nums
    FROM master..spt_values
    ) a
WHERE DATENAME(WEEKDAY , DATEADD(DAY, Nums , @Date )) = 'Saturday'
```

I have parameterised it, just so you can use it more than just today's date.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to pivot those dates so they are in a ; separated list and also tie them to the row regardless of date. So if my row has a date  of 2012-01-01 it returns those values without the parameter. @Date

Comment: @user385605 then you need to update your question as that's not obvious at all